# Code to get incremental excel column name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, excel

I want to create a loop which increments the column name of excel from a starting point.
For Example:
If I start the column name from `X` so as long as I keep increment the character by 1 It should return the output like - `Y`, `Z`, `AA`, `AB`,..., `AZ`, `BA`, `BB`,... .

The starting of Excel column name is `A` and code should be able to return the column name with atleast 5 characters i.e. `ZZZZZ`, untill loop continues.

This is what I tried, but can't handle for increasing column name after `Z`:

```
var i3;
var text3 = "";
var c;

for(i3 = 65; 90 >= i3; i3++) {
    c = String.fromCharCode(i3);
    text3 += c + ", ";
}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Haven't done any javascript in several years so this is purely logic-based.
Could have a while loop going which calculates the MOD(i3Check,26)>0 with MOD being function to check what the remaining is of i3Check/26, i.e. 27/26 = 1

Something like this in your for loop (don't forget var i3Check):

```
c = ""
i3Check = i3
While(MOD(i3Check,26)>0){
    c = c+String.fromCharCode(26);
    i3Check = i3Check - 26;
}
If(i3Check>0){
     c = String.fromCharCode(i3Check) + c;
}
```

I have no way to test this nor do I know the syntax anymore for javascript but it should be close :p